# Split in Google BigQuery

Tags: sql-server, google-bigquery, google-query-language

I have a problem with my Google BigQuery using Split. I have a column named Account like:

```
"E-mail UK"    
"Shopping New Zealand"
"Shopping South Africa"
```

I need to split the country from Account. I used the below syntax

`SPLIT(Account,' ')[OFFSET(1)]`

but it gives the result like:

```
Country    
Uk    
New    
South
```

How can I get all the whole string after the first space in Google BigQuery?

Many thanks

Answer (score 3):

Regular expressions:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE (account, r'^[^ ]* ', '')
```

Comment: @user123 you can also accept the answer so that the community knows the issue is solved

Answer (score 3):

> get all the whole string after the first space

Alternative option is:

BigQuery Standard SQL

```
SUBSTR(Account, STRPOS(Account, ' '))
```

BigQuery Legacy SQL

```
SUBSTR(Account, INSTR(Account, ' '))
```